# How do I get the entire dependency tree of a helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to get the entire dependency tree of a helm chart.
Preferably I don't want to download any chart at all.
I would also prefer to get the charts as they are in the charts.lock file to get the actual real version and actual sha (again preferably without downloading any chart).

Comment: Is there a programming-related aspect to this question; why are you asking and what code have you already written?  The lock file will contain a flattened list of the dependencies, and I believe the only place a dependency's further dependencies are listed is that dependency chart's `Chart.yaml`/`requirements.yaml`; you must download the dependency to get that.

Comment: Are you sure that the lock file contains a flattened list of all dependencies?

E.g:
Take a look at [this spring-cloud-dataflow Chart.lock file](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow/Chart.lock) it contains `rabbitmq`, `mariadb`, `kafka`, and `common` as dependencies.

However, kafka's `Chart.lock` file [also contains zookeeper](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/kafka/Chart.lock#L2) which is not listed in the original spring-cloud-dataflow `Chart.lock` file.

Comment: I might be wrong there.  That bit of research seems like it answers your question, though – if a parent chart can have indirect dependencies that aren't mentioned anywhere in the parent, then it seems like it would be impossible to derive a complete dependency tree without downloading the immediate dependencies?

Comment: Yup seems so, I ended up writing the code that does the downloading and recursively retrieves dependencies. It seems inefficient to download the entire chart folder each time because the only thing I really need is to download the Chart.lock files or Chart.yaml (in case Chart.lock doesn't exist).